# How to send a form request (method = POST) to a page using the initial addres?

Tags: python, http, post, request

I need to solve this problem. I have to send a form using post request, but I have to send it to the page where the form is, and in all the solutions that I find to send the request you have to send it to the page where the results come, and to me this doesn't work because the page that I need to send the request to has a specific SID to each search you enter. Is there any way I could do this?

Example of code that doesn't work for my problem:

```
post_data = [("doesn't","work")]
result = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.for.my.problem', urllib.urlencode(post_data))
content = result.read()
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the request needs to send to same page where the request comes, why just call the response method directly since they are in the same page, the method can be accessed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood this. Am I supposed to just send the initial? address in this code? But if I do this I get the form page as response, not the result page.

Comment: Here's my understanding of your problem
`1. You have a form on one page to collect data
 2. You want to submit the data to code block in the same page to  process`
If my assumption is right and there's no request to server, you can choose Javascript. `When clicking submit button, trigger an javascript function in the same page, then handle all the data in that function`